# Why is the distribution from SmoothHistogram3D NOT normalized?

Tags: graphics, histograms

I am plotting a intensity distribution by SmoothHistogram3D. It is a actually a heatmap from list of coordinates,{xcart,ycart}.

The plotting looks great, except the z value is not within the range of 0-1. I am confusing, I think the option "PDF" should have normalized the data.

```
xcart = r Cos[Phi]; 
ycart = r Sin[Phi];
nvcart = Thread[{xcart, ycart}];
SmoothHistogram3D[nvcart, Automatic, "PDF", 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> 50]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't grasp the underlying maths.

Answer (score 3):

`"PDF"` means that the volume under the surface is 1, not that the maximum is 1.  The peak may be any positive number, even greater than 1, depending on the data.

Comment: Thanks! I had some misunderstanding on the probability density.

Comment: @user58177 In other words, the PDF is a probability *density* function. It is a density, not a probability.